# Does the 'President' have 2 Billion Leaves?

Tags: botany, trees

The world's second-largest known tree, the President, in Sequoia National Park is 3200 years old and is said to have 2 billion leaves (Source: https://youtu.be/vNCH6uhB_Bs?t=59).

Is this correct? And how was this number arrived at?

In other words, how is such an insanely large number possible?

Comment: The US National Park Rangers count them. But that makes it a mathematical question, not a biological one, so it should be obvious that it is off topic here.

Comment: Strictly speaking, S. giganteum is a conifer so it has needles, not leaves. So count the individual needles on one twig (they're really small), multiply by the number of twigs per branch and the number of branches on the tree.

Comment: @David That number was obviously not 'counted'. It was arrived at by an estimate based on botanical facts.

Comment: @jamesqf Thank you! That explains the huge number which was my primary curiosity. Could you please add it as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: If you know the answer, why ask the question?

Comment: @David I want to know what botanical facts made that estimated number so huge.

Comment: Botanical facts? I imagined they extrapolated from the empirical observations of the numbers of leaves per branch and the number if branches per metre rise in the trunk, allowing for the pattern of sub-branching. But it is hardly a question of biological principle. As I have indicated, it may be answered by some general mathematical formula, if you plug in the constants. A good scientific exercise, but not a question likely to find interest or answer here, I would imagine.

Comment: @Ritesh Singh: Because it's not an answer, just my guess at how that number might have been arrived at.  I don't know how whoever did that video got their number...

Comment: @jamesqf It is closest to an answer. My main question was how is such an insanely large number possible.

Comment: @RiteshSingh, I upvoted your question. As a physicist that's a member of a lot of Stack exchanges, I wonder if you could help us by committing to the [Materials Modeling](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/122958/materials-modeling?referrer=OGMwYmViMzQ3MGRmZjE2ZGExMmVhYTlkYjc5MDYxNTdjN2JhOGVjMjIzMGViZjdlZWEwYzZhMzM3NGU5OTEyYY6iRI2mgUY2hY4fGs-XFsqk4r8veLeAOOIVNCBJTshg0) proposal? We really need help, and would very much appreciate if you could commit!

Comment: @user1271772 Done sir/madam, Thank you! :)

Comment: @user1271772 Also recruited a few friends to commit to it :)

Comment: @RiteshSingh! Thank you so much !!!!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way* to come up with an estimate of how many leaves - or needles, in the case of Sequoiadendron giganteum - is simply to count the number of leaves on a twig (or a number, to get a good average), then the number of twigs on a branch, and then count the branches on the tree, after which it's just multiplication.

Now one reason that the number seems so high is the way the needles grow.  Unlike for instance pines, which have long needles arranged in sparse clusters of 2, 3, or 5, or spruce & fir, which have medium needles arranged along the branches, the sequoia has lots of tiny needles arranged on twiglets.

Link with picture of sequoia needles: https://www.monumentaltrees.com/en/trees/giantsequoia/giantsequoia/
Picture of pine vs spruce & fir: https://www.finegardening.com/article/fir-vs-spruce-vs-pine-how-to-tell-them-apart

*But I don't know whether it's the way used to get the number in the link.

Comment: Thank you for the pics. This answer completely satisfies by curiosity! :)